# PHP echo function changing order of html output?

Tags: php, html, echo

The function getUserAvatar outputs the following :

```
 <img src="http://pathtoimage/image.jpg" height="16" width="16" alt="avatar" />
```

I'm calling it within a particular div.

When I call it like this is works perfectly :

```
 echo '<div class="avatar">';
 echo getUserAvatar($avatar_id);
 echo '</div>';
```

Resulting in the following html output :

```
 <div class="avatar"><img src="http://pathtoimage/image.jpg" height="16" width="16" alt="avatar" /></div>
```

But when I try to put it all on one line :

```
 echo '<div class="avatar">' .getUserAvatar($avatar_id). '</div>';
```

It results in the following html, executing the function before rendering the div tags? :

```
 <img src="http://pathtoimage/image.jpg" height="16" width="16" alt="avatar" /><div class="avatar"></div>
```

Could somebody please explain why this is and offer the correct solution?

Comment: are you returning or printing content in your `getUserAvatar` function?

Comment: you have to `return` the string in your `getUserAvatar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function getUserAvatar($avatar_id) {
    // your function body
    return $your_return_id;
}

echo '<div class="avatar">' .getUserAvatar($avatar_id). '</div>';
```